# exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved'

Tags: content-editor, copy

Whenever I try and copy a single item anywhere, I get this error. I have serialized the item and it has a template.

NOTE: This is an item in a branch

```
12304 14:24:32 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Exception[1]: System.ArgumentNullException 
Message[1]: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: itemTemplate 
Source[1]: Sitecore.Kernel 
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.Processors.Deploy.DeployItem[TDefinition](Item item, Template itemTemplate, ID expectedTemplateId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.Processors.Deploy.Process(DeployDefinitionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.DeployDefinition.DeployDefinitionPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Core.IgnoreRecursiveCalls.Run(ID id, Action action)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.DeployDefinition.DeployDefinitionPipeline.Run(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 


12304 14:24:32 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID: {A4BF4831-F182-4F02-BD90-C7EF018285EA}, database: master
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
```

Comment: Is the item related to Sitecore Marketing definition? Also, what is the Sitecore version?

Comment: No, see my answer. Doh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to file this under doh. I'll leave this question for anyone who sees this error.

This is because the **template for the item does not exist** in the local environment. That's embarrassing.